# Unable to retrieve data from firebase realtime database into web app

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to develop a web blog app,  where people can come and upload different blogs and can read blogs uploaded by others too. I was able to successfully upload the data on the firebase real-time database, but I am facing an issue while trying to retrieve data from firebase. I have a card from google material library and I want the title and desc to be displayed there below. But whenever I am trying to retrieve the data only data from the last node is getting displayed. Below is my code for html and javascript.

HTML code:

```
<div class="w">
            <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="titlePost">Welcome</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" id="descPost">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" href="post.html">
      Get Started
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__menu">
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
     </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");

rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
    var title = snap.child("Title").val();
        var desc = snap.child("desc").val();

        
        $("#titlePost").text(title);
        $("#descPost").text(desc);
});
```

Below is the pic of my database.

[image]

and here's what my retrieved data looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xh3o.png)
Only one node is retrieved

Comment: `here's what my retrieved data looks like` no, that's a picture, not data

Comment: what were you expecting? each `child_added` replaces the `title` and `desc`

Comment: then what do u suggest I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your posts in a list so that a new child won't replace your old child, if it is in a list it will just extend the list. Your parent in this case is the 
"ul" which is callled "blog-posts", and you are going to append childs to this list like in the example below. Your children will expand this list and not overwrite each other

```
<body>
<div>
    <ul class="blog-posts">
        <li>
            <!--Your Posts are here-->
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="titlePost">Welcome</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" id="descPost">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
parent.append(`
    <li>
    <div class="w">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="${key}">${title}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" id="descPost">
        ${desc}
      </div>
    </div>
    <li/>`
);
```

Comment: Please explain how to do that to provide a good answer. You can do that with a sample code

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but I seriously don't have any idea how to implement it, so a little sample of hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really worked for me after some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

> Only one node is retrieved

That seems unlikely. You can easily check this, by adding some simple logging and then checking the developer console of your browser:

```
rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
    var title = snap.child("Title").val();
    var desc = snap.child("desc").val();
    console.log(title);

    $("#titlePost").text(title);
    $("#descPost").text(desc);
});
```

My expectation is that you'll see each title being logged. But since you always call `$("#titlePost").text(title);`, you only see the title of the last post in the HTML.

A simple fix is to just append the titles in the HTML:

```
$("#titlePost").append(title);
```

Now with this, you'll see all titles concatenated together. That's the correct content, but it probably looks horrible.

So the proper solution is to generate a bit of HTML around each title and description. As far as I can see, this is what you use:

```
rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
    var key = snap.key;
    var title = snap.child("Title").val();
    var desc = snap.child("desc").val();

    var parent = $("#titlePost").parent().parent().parent();
    parent.append(`<div class="w">
        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
          <div class="mdl-card__title">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="${key}">${title}</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" id="descPost">
            ${desc}
          </div>
        </div>`
    );
});
```

Comment: sir each of the data is getting retrieved, I have already created alert for the retrieved title, and all the titles are shown but instead, only the last one gets displayed.

Comment: $("#titlePost").parent().parent().parent();                                                               
   just to be sure sir what would come in place of parent(sorry really new in HTML)

Comment: Try each of my snippets please, as they build up to a better solution. In general you will need to learn to generate HTML with the content of the database in it. My third snippet is a simple version of that, but you'd do well to research that approach further.

Comment: `$("#titlePost").parent().parent().parent()` just looks up the element in the HTML to add the new content under. If you know the ID of that element, you can also look it up with `$("#idOfParent")`.

Comment: appending the data was a good idea but I had to put it inside the list first like @sertsedat said but thank you anyway.